# How can I register user's ios device for receiving push messages from place other than AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

Currently in my `appDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I'm calling the following methods:

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I also have the following methods implemented in `AppDelegate`:

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

When user starts my app for the first time, he sees the popup that ask him for permission about receiving push messages.

I want to postpone showing this popup until user manually chooses specific option in Settings menu.

In Settings menu I have a `UISwitch` and I'm checking the state of it every time user changes it:

```
func messagesStateChanged(_ sender: UISwitch){
    if(sender.isOn){
        defaults.set("true", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()
    } else {
        defaults.set("false", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Is there a way of moving the `push` handling from app delegate to the settings menu, so that user sees the popup not immediately after starting the app, but when he selects the `UISwitch`? Also - will that work for future and all `push` functionality works well if I move it to Settings class?

Comment: Why do you want to make worse an approved and standardized design pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `UIApplication` instance provided to you in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` by accessing `UIApplication.shared` class property from anywhere in your application, where you have access to `UIKit`. I usually create a wrapper class that manages notifications, which would allow you to inject `UIApplication` dependency when you're writing unit tests later.

**The register calls should happen when you're activating the switch:**

```
func messagesStateChanged(_ sender: UISwitch){
    if(sender.isOn){
        defaults.set("true", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()

        let application = UIApplication.shared
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        defaults.set("false", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

A simplified wrapper class I use (singleton used for simplicity):

```
class NotificationManager {
    static var shared = NotificationManager()

    private var application : UIApplication?

    func setup(application: UIApplication) {
        self.application = application
    }

    func register () {
        guard let application = application else {
            print("Attempt to register without calling setup")
            return
        }

        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

This requires that you call setup in your `didFinishLaunchingMethod`:

```
NotificationManager.shared.setup(application: application)
```

But then wherever you need to register for the notifications:

```
func messagesStateChanged(_ sender: UISwitch){
    if(sender.isOn){
        ...
        NotificationManager.shared.register()
    }
    ...
}
```

This allows you to easily test `NotificationManager` class by injecting an `UIApplication` mock object later on and the class also nicely encapsulates all notification related logic. With some modifications it can easily keep track if you already registered, keep track of the push token you received and even handle iOS 8/9 backward compatibility without duplicating boilerplate code.

Comment: could you please share a sample code of that wrapper class?

Comment: There you go. Use this more as an idea, rather than using this solution directly.

Comment: I asked a follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025023/why-i-cannot-register-my-device-for-apple-push-messages-after-unregistering-from could you take a look?