# why I cannot register my device for apple push messages after unregistering from it?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications

This is a followup to my previous question asked here [How can I register user's ios device for receiving push messages from place other than AppDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866890/how-can-i-register-users-ios-device-for-receiving-push-messages-from-place-othe)

Currently in my `Swift` application I have a `UISwitch` that is set to off by default and when user turns it on - I want him to register for receiving push notifications. However, when he turns that switch off - he should unregister from push notifications (and do not receive any push msgs later on until registering again).

So I created a class for managing push registration:

```
class NotificationManager {
    static var shared = NotificationManager()

    private var application : UIApplication?

    func setup(application: UIApplication) {
        self.application = application
    }

    func register () {
        guard let application = application else {
            print("Attempt to register without calling setup")
            return
        }
        print("registering for push")
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func unregister(){

        guard let application = application else {
            print("Attempt to register without calling setup")
            return
        }
        print("unregistering for push")
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        if(application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications){
            print("unregistering went ok")
            application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
        }



    }
}
```

and then my listener of `UISwitch` is:

```
func messagesStateChanged(_ sender: UISwitch){
    if(sender.isOn){
        defaults.set("true", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()
        NotificationManager.shared.register()
    } else {
        defaults.set("false", forKey: "popupMessages")
        defaults.synchronize()
        NotificationManager.shared.unregister()
    }
}
```

Now in my `AppDelegate` I have the following method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)

}
```

and when user turns on the switch for the first time - I see the string `registering for push` and device token printed in the console.

When user then turns off the switch, I see in console:

```
unregistering for push
unregistering went ok
```

But then, when I turn on the switch again, I only see:

```
registering for push
```

and I don't see a token string. Seems like the method from `AppDelegate`: `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is never called. When I turn off the switch later on, I also only see:

```
unregistering for push
```

and I'm not getting a confirmation that `unregistering went ok`.

Why I cannot unregister and then register again for push messages?

I've designed it all like this because I want to add user a choice for receiving push notifications or not directly in my application.

Comment: I dont know what solution you are using, I use parse server and in that case, I have one field where my cloud code send push only for the checked registers

Comment: Because APNS works that way. It stores the setting so it does not bother user every time. To reset this, you need to delete the app from device (sometimes the setting is even cached for 24 hours).

Comment: @Legoless. Yes, but this all works before iOS10. Also, we have an issue with offline logout. If we can't unregister, when the Internet appears user can receive notifications, but he shouldn't.